# Windows Sever 2016に.Net Framework　4.5.2はインストール可能ですか？

Tags: c#, windows

タイトルの件、以下を参考にするとwindows server 2016に
.net framework 4.5.2がインストールできるのか
心配です。
クライアント：windows 7/8/10 .net frame 4.5.2
サーバ:windows server 2016 .net frame 4.5.2
でシステム構築を検討しております。

http://qiita.com/nskydiving/items/3af8bab5a0a63ccb9893

どなたがご経験がある方コメントを頂ければと思います。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.NET Framework のバージョンおよび依存関係](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx)で説明されていますが、.NET Framework 4以降はインプレース更新のため、１つのバージョンしかインストールできません。
その上で、Windows 8以降については

- Windows 8は4.5
- Windows 8.1は4.5.1
- Windows 10は4.6以降

がインストールされているため、それ以前のバージョンに戻すこともできません。Windows Serverについても同様です。

.NET Frameworkには下位互換がありますので、4.5.2で開発しておいて、インストールされているバージョンで動作させることになるでしょう。